# Java: How to write computing data in arraylist?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

Hello guys I'am beginner of the Java and i've got some problems with array&arraylist. My main problem is how to write computing, dynamic data into the array and later how to read it? Here's my weird code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    int yil, bolum = 0, kalan;
    Scanner klavye = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList liste = new ArrayList();

    //or shall i use this? >> int[] liste = new int[10];

    System.out.println("Yıl Girin: "); // enter the 1453
    yil = klavye.nextInt();

    do{ // process makes 1453 separate then write in the array or arraylist. [1, 4, 5, 3]

    kalan = yil % 10;
    liste.add(kalan); //my problem starts in here. How can i add "kalan" into the "liste".
    bolum = yil / 10;
    yil = bolum;

    }while( bolum == 0 );

    System.out.println("Sayının Basamak Sayısı: " + liste.size()); //in here read the number of elements of the "liste" 
    klavye.close();
}
```

Edit:

```
    //needs to be like that
    while( bolum != 0 ); 
    System.out.println("Sayının Basamak Sayısı: " + liste);
```

Comment: Seems like you are doing things right.. What went wrong? or Why did you stop here? Go on.

Comment: Good. Now all you need is to `get()` your items from the list. Please complete what you are trying to do with the list.

Comment: Looks fine to me. What java version do you use? The code should compile and provide the expected results for Java 5 and above.

Comment: When i enter to the number it writes into the array like this: [1453] and it shows 1 element not 4.

Comment: Do you mean it prints `Sayının Basamak Sayısı: 1` ? what is "shown" is the size of the `liste` - since it is what you ask for.

Comment: I think you want your condition to be `while( bolum != 0)`, because it will only equal 0 when there are no more digits left in your number

Comment: @HunterMcMillen: It is most likely it. You should add it as an answer (and note the edge case where the initial number is 0 itself)

Comment: @HunterMcMillen. Yo Hunter. You hunt the mistake.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen absolutely like that, thank you so much guys!

Comment: @HunterMcMillen I want to ask one more thing :)   


  System.out.println("Sayının Basamak Sayısı: " + liste.size()); //With this line I print the decimal places. No problem in here.  
  System.out.println("Sayının Tersi: " + liste.toString()); // This line I print number of elements like that [3, 5, 4, 1]. Now i try to reverse the number effortlessly :) But i stuck in the comas and brackets. My question is how can I directly show it like 3541 ?

Comment: @android93 You can just build the String yourself, iterate through your ArrayList and add every element to a String then print that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that you most likely want your loop stopping condition to be:

```
while( bolum != 0)
```

because `bolum` will only be `0` when there are no more digits left in your number to process. Also, as amit mentions above it could be the case that the user entered `0` when prompted for a number, so you should take that into account.

Comment: @android93. I think this the major problem you are having with your code. apart from printing the list as in ARS answer.

Answer (score 1):

To obtain a string representation of your `ArrayList` (showing the elements it contains through their string representations), you can just use

```
System.out.println("Sayının Basamak Sayısı: " + liste);
```

No need to convert to an array. This works because it causes `liste`'s [`toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#toString%28%29) method to be called (which is why we don't need to call it explicitly).

Answer (score 0):

You must change this line:

```
}while( bolum == 0 );
```

To this:

```
}while( bolum > 0 );
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to print your elements in the ArrayList, update your last statement to print as below:

```
  System.out.println("Sayının Basamak Sayısı: " + liste);
```

Or you can iterate your list and print as :

```
 for(Object i: liste){
    System.out.println(i);
 }
```

This will print your individual list items in separate lines.

**Also please fix your while condition as `while(bolum != 0);`** as it may terminate after the very first iteration as `bolum` will be non zero i.e.  `1, 2...(!= 0)`.

Comment: Why you need to convert it to array and then use toString?

Comment: @RohitJain: Updated the answer to use `toString()`.

Comment: @android93: You are welcome. If the posts here helped you, please don't forget to accept the answer you like.

Comment: @YogendraSingh. You don't need toString too. just printing the `list` will automatically invoke `toString`. Writing `toString` is just extra 11 keystrokes. Count it starting from `.`

Comment: @RohitJain Correct. Thanks for pointing it out, but that doesn't make my answer incorrect. This help in practice as you see lots of question coming around, object itself being printed.

Comment: @YogendraSingh. Yeah that of course doesn't make your answer incorrect. But it does not solve the problem rather in the code. The problem was something else, which you can see from the accepted answer.